# Using variant array to update cells

Tags: excel, vba

In the following subset of code, I am trying to have Excel vba update the second column by adding an apostrophe to the beginning of each cell in the range. How do I reference each cell to add apostrophe to after this line:

> myRange = .Range("b2:b").Value

Here is the rest of the code so far:

```
> Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
> 
> Dim objExcel As Excel.Application Dim objWB As Excel.Workbook Dim
> objWBtoAdd As Excel.Workbook Dim newWS As Excel.Worksheet Dim objWS As
> Excel.Worksheet Dim i As Long Dim myRange As Range Dim Cell As Range
> 
>   Set objExcel = New Excel.Application   objExcel.Visible = True   Set
> objWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\TEST\Drop\Bank.xlsx", , False) Set
> objWBtoAdd = Workbooks.Add Set newWS = objWBtoAdd.ActiveSheet   Set
> objWS = objWB.ActiveSheet
>  
>     With objWS
>    
>         
>         myRange = .Range("b2:b").Value
>         
>         .Range("b2:b").Value = myRange
>         
>                  
>     
>     End With
> 
>  
> 
> 
> 
> End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("b2:b")` is not a valid range.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

- declares and assigns `objWBtoAdd` and `newWS` but they're not used anywhere
- variables `i` and `cell` are also not used
- It simply attempts to assign an invalid range `.Range("b2:b").Value` to another Range variable
- Then the Range variable back to the invalid range, without modifying the values

This notation is not a valid Range: `.Range("b2:b")`

- It should contain the address of 1st cell - `"B2"` & `":"` & `"B9"` (address of last cell in range)

If you need to *"update the second column by adding an apostrophe to the beginning of each cell in the range"* and copy the column to a new sheet, try the code bellow

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdTest_Click()

    Const INI_PATH = "C:\TEST\Drop\Bank.xlsx"
    Const NEW_PATH = "C:\TEST\Drop\BankNew.xlsx"

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application: Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Dim wbIni As Excel.Workbook:    Set wbIni = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(INI_PATH, , False)
    Dim wbNew As Excel.Workbook:    Set wbNew = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet, colBIni As Range, colBNew As Range, lr As Long

    'xlApp.Visible = True
    Set ws = wbIni.ActiveSheet  'Prefer explicit: Set ws = wbIni.Worksheets("Sheet3")

    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Set colBIni = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "B"), ws.Cells(lr, "B"))
    Set ws = wbNew.ActiveSheet  'Prefer explicit: Set ws = wbNew.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set colBNew = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "B"), ws.Cells(lr, "B"))

    Dim arr As Variant, r As Long

    arr = colBIni.Value2            'copy colB to array
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(r, 1) = "'" & arr(r, 1) 'modify array values
    Next
    'colBIni.Value2 = arr           'paste array to colB (Ini file)
    colBNew.Value2 = arr            'paste array to colB (New file)

    wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:=NEW_PATH   'Save new File
    wbIni.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

---

.

If column B contains only formulas, or URLs you don't need to use a `For` loop

```
With ws.UsedRange.Columns("B")  'all cells with data (and formatting) in column B
    .Replace "=", "'="
    .Replace "https://", "'https://"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for this—. Sorry for the delay in responding...  B